# Error executing: CREATE DATABASE CARS . Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE[*] DATABASE CARS

Tags: sql, h2

When I am trying to run my SQL script that contains only 1 line :

```
CREATE DATABASE CARS;
```

I receive an ERROR :

```
Error executing: ﻿CREATE DATABASE CARS
.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "﻿CREATE[*] DATABASE CARS
"; SQL statement:   
CREATE DATABASE CARS
 [42000-199]
```

I use h2 database embedded in IDEA and use SQL Dialect - posgtres.

Run in with help of RunScript :

```
     ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(conn);
        //Creating a reader object
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\PROJECTS\\src\\main\\resources\\createDatabaseAndUser.sql"));
        //Running the script
        sr.runScript(reader);
```

Comment: For what **RDBMS** is this??

Comment: @marc_s It is the first script, then I will work with students, courses and groups of students.
First of all, I need to create database and user in one script.

Comment: [As documented in the manual](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html) h2 does not have a CREATE DATABASE command. You probably want CREATE SCHEMA

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But I still have the same error